# Filter prefetch_related empty in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

Is it possible to Select Pizzas with their Toppings, but only those pizzas, that have certain number of toppings, like 0,1,2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can filter on the number of toppings by annotating the queryset, then filtering it.

```
from django.db.models import Count

pizzas = Pizza.objects.annotate(
    num_toppings=Count('toppings'),
).filter(num_toppings__lt=3)
```

You can then use `prefetch_related` the same way that you do for other querysets.

```
pizzas = Pizza.objects.annotate(
    num_toppings=Count('toppings'),
).filter(num_toppings__lt=3).prefetch_related('toppings')
```