# How to exclude instances with empty querysets in prefetch_related?

Tags: python, django, orm, annotate, django-prefetch-related

I have two models - `Project` and `Contract`. 
They have one-to-many relationship.

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

I get a qs of `Project` instances with relevant `Contract` instance(s).

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(active=True).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('contract_set', queryset=Contract.objects.filter(**filters), to_attr='contracts')
    )
```

But now I need to get `Project` instances with exact `Contract` instance by putting `Contract` guid to `filters`.

```
filters: Dict = {
  'guid': some_guid,
}
```

But I receive all `Project` instances where only one has not empty `contracts` attr and others `Project` instances have empty `contracts` attr.

I found such issues:
[How to exclude rows with empty prefetch_related field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863770/how-to-exclude-rows-with-empty-prefetch-related-field)
[Filter prefetch_related empty in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882577/filter-prefetch-related-empty-in-django) 
but they do not help me.

I tried such options:
a) using `OuterRef` and `Exist`:

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(**filters_projects).annotate(
    has_contracts=Exists(
        Contract.objects.filter(project_id=OuterRef('pk'), **filters_contracts)
    )
)

projects = projects.filter(has_contracts=True)
```

b) using `annotate`:

```
projects = (
        Project.objects.filter(**filters_projects)
        .annotate(num_contracts=Count('contract'))
        .exclude(num_contracts=0)
        .prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('contract_set', queryset=Contract.objects.filter(**filters_contracts), to_attr='contracts')
        )
    )
```

They do not work for me...

How can I implement the required functionality?

Comment: What is not working with the `Exists`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to filter both in the `Prefetch` object *and* the `Project`, so:

```
projects = (
    Project.objects.filter(
        Exists(
            Contract.objects.filter(
                project_id=OuterRef('pk'), **filters_contracts
            )
        ),
        **filters_projects
    )
    .prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'contract_set',
            queryset=Contract.objects.filter(**filters_contracts),
            to_attr='contracts',
        )
    )
    .distinct()
)
```

So you use the `**filters_contracts` twice: once to only retrieve these `Project`s once, and once for the prefetched object.